# Hidden field value not rendering in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, webforms, hidden-field

I have a hidden field in a data bound GridView which is not rendering it's value in IE 11.0.9600.

**.aspx**

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" Value='<%# ((MyObject)Container.DataItem).MyEnumValue.ToString() %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Rendered Output**

*Chrome/Firefox*

```
<input type="hidden" name="..." id="..." value="MyEnumStringValue">
```

*IE*

```
<input name="..." id="..." type="hidden"></input>
```

Same name, same id, no value in ie and no closing tag in Chrome/Firefox!

What do I need to do to get the value to render? Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Did you add a ControlAdapter class for the HiddenField control?

Comment: @angrymrt No, I've never needed to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following with the expected results:
aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" Value='<%# ((MyObject)Container.DataItem).MyEnumValue.ToString() %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    grid.DataSource = new[] { 
        new MyObject()
        {
            MyEnumValue = MyEnum.MyEnumStringValue,
        }};
    grid.DataBind();
}

public class MyObject
{
    public MyEnum MyEnumValue { get; set; }
}
public enum MyEnum
{
    MyEnumStringValue,
}
```

This results in:
Chrome 32.0.1700.107:

```
<input type="hidden" name="grid$ctl02$hdnField" id="grid_hdnField_0" value="MyEnumStringValue">
```

IE 11.0.9600.16518:

```
<input name="grid$ctl02$hdnField" id="grid_hdnField_0" type="hidden" value="MyEnumStringValue">
```

So the problem probably lies somewhere else, can you post more code/details?

Comment: I've actually left this company now so no longer have access to the code. If it works in a vanilla setup then it must have been something else in the page/site or a bug in the particular version of IE I was using (no access now). Thanks